# How to add html link on multiple location on google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, maps

I used this tutorial, https://www.create.net/support/218-how-to-pin-point-multiple-locations-on-google-maps.html to add a multiple location on my gmap. And, it works fine.

But, I want to add a HTML link in the description. I tried to add code `<html> <a href="#"> Sample link </a> </html>` in the description field of the each location, but it seems that it's not accepting html code.

[Image shows it's not accepting html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayFsC.png)

**How can I achieve this?**

So, if the user click on a marker location he/she can click on a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

if you just type in URL with http(s), it'll become a hyper link.

However, you cannot style it any other way.

[image: Hyper link in Description]